# Getting connection refused when trying to connect Questdb to Grafana

Tags: questdb

I'm running QuestDB in docker and exposing the postgres port on 8812:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 9009:9009 -p 8812:8812 questdb/questdb:6.0.2
```

Then I'm running grafana with

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
```

I get an error saying connection refused: [screenshot of the grafana setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtaQK.png)
How can I connect grafana properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are running QuestDB via docker and Grafana via docker, which means that they run in their own network which is different from what you are exposing.

To solve your issue, you need to find the IP of the questDB network (within docker) and connect Grafana to it.

1. In your terminal type: `docker network inspect bridge`. this will open a list of jsons.
2. Under `"Containers"` you should see both `"Name": "grafana".` and `"Name": "questdb".`. You are looking for `questdb`'s `IPv4Address` before the `/`. For example the ``IPv4Address `can be something like:  "122.12.0.3/22"` - so you need just the `122.12.0.3`.
3. Now go to your Grafana UI and use `122.12.0.3` to make the connection as described [here](https://questdb.io/docs/third-party-tools/grafana).